# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BASE_COLORS'

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

Thanks for your time! My code is in python and I want to plot some graph to see the colors in the graph. The code is :

```
"""
Visualization of named colors.

Simple plot example with the named colors and its visual representation.
"""

from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function,
                        unicode_literals)
import six

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors


colors = dict(mcolors.BASE_COLORS, **mcolors.CSS4_COLORS)

# Sort by hue, saturation, value and name.
by_hsv = sorted((tuple(mcolors.rgb_to_hsv(mcolors.to_rgba(color)[:3])), name)
                for name, color in colors.items())

# Get the sorted color names.
sorted_names = [name for hsv, name in by_hsv]

n = len(sorted_names)
ncols = 4
nrows = int(np.ceil(1. * n / ncols))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))

X, Y = fig.get_dpi() * fig.get_size_inches()

# row height
h = Y / (nrows + 1)
# col width
w = X / ncols

for i, name in enumerate(sorted_names):
    col = i % ncols
    row = int(i / ncols)
    y = Y - (row * h) - h

    xi_line = w * (col + 0.05)
    xf_line = w * (col + 0.25)
    xi_text = w * (col + 0.3)

    ax.text(xi_text, y, name, fontsize=(h * 0.8),
            horizontalalignment='left',
            verticalalignment='center')

    ax.hlines(
        y + h * 0.1, xi_line, xf_line, color=colors[name], linewidth=(h * 0.6))

ax.set_xlim(0, X)
ax.set_ylim(0, Y)
ax.set_axis_off()

fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1,
                    top=1, bottom=0,
                    hspace=0, wspace=0)
plt.show()
```

But the program is not executable and reports the following error message:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BASE_COLORS'. How should I run the program?

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are you using? (you find out via `import matplotlib` `print (matplotlib.__version__)`

Comment: The version is 1.3.1.

Comment: I updated matplotlib version to v2.0 now.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your matplotlib to version 2.0+ then this should work. Both BASE_COLORS and CSS4_COLORS are defined in this.

Answer (score 0):

The code is the well known [named_colors example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html) from the matplotlib page.

Depending on the version of matplotlib you are running, the example will or will not work. However previous version's examples are still available:

v2.0:   http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html
v1.5:   http://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/examples/color/named_colors.html
v*x*.*y*.*z*: http://matplotlib.org/x.y.z/examples/color/named_colors.html

Comment: The error is disappeared now but nothing is still displaying :(

Comment: There is not any thing now. No error. No image. But I can save the figure by replacing  plt.show() with plt.savefig('example.jpg').

I think the error is because of backend now . I guess I should use pyplot.switch_backends() to change the backend but don't know how exactly must do it. now the backend value is  'agg'. I get it by matplotlib.get_backend() command.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade matplotlib to version 2.0+ . BASE_COLORS and other things are defined there.

To upgrade use command:

```
$python -m pip install --user matplotlib --upgrade
```